# MVVMCross side menu with mixed forms/native views

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Is there a way to have a side menu on iOS (navigation Drawer) on Android that uses a native view for the menu, but uses Xamarin.Forms pages for the content?

The Forms view presenter doesn't seem to support this setup.

The template that I'm using embeds the fragment in a frame on Android.

```
    [MvxFragmentPresentation(typeof(MainContainerViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame)]
    public class MainFragment : BaseFragment<MainViewModel>
```

And on iOS it uses this hint.

```
    [MvxSidebarPresentation(MvxPanelEnum.Center, MvxPanelHintType.ResetRoot, false)]
    public class MainViewController : BaseViewController<MainViewModel>
```

I'm trying to do something like this with a ContentPage instead.

```
[MvxContentPagePresentationAttribute(AndroidFrameId = "content_frame", iOSPanel=MvxPanelEnum.Center)]
public partial class MainPage : MvxContentPage<MainViewModel>
```

Comment: You should know that Xamarin forms is a cross platform native mobile application platform meaning all the views you see are "native"

Comment: @Prateek Yes. But how should I differentiate a forms page from a viewController or a Fragment?

Comment: @Hackmodford are you trying to embed native code into xamarin forms content page or you want to create a MasterDetail page ?

Comment: @FabriBertani Trying to convert an existing Xamarin.Forms app (that uses shell for a flyout menu) to MVVMCross so that I could add more views that are created in Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android and share a viewController.

Comment: As far as i know, MvvmCross doesn't support XF shell yet. First use `MvxMasterDetailPage` in order to get side menu, check the [MvvmCross Playground](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground) to see how to do it, then you can check [this](https://michaelridland.com/xamarin/mixing-xamarin-forms-mvvmcross-nativeviews/) and  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms) to learn how to mix/embed native views in XF